# Same value can be selected in other dropdown list as already selected in prev dropdown list using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have four dropdown list of Countries, if I have selected India in the first dropdown list then I cannot select INDIA in another dropdown list. In below code I am able to display method but after displaying message I am able to see duplicate value in another dropdown list.

```
if ($('#ddlTitanVlanLocationA :selected').text() == $('#ddlTitanVlanLocationB :selected').text() || $('#ddlTitanVlanLocationA :selected').text() == $('#ddlTitanVlanLocationC :selected').text() || $('#ddlTitanVlanLocationA :selected').text() == $('#ddlTitanVlanLocationD :selected').text()) {
    alert("You have already selected same value in other Location field. Please select different value.!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: can you post your full code ?

Comment: Sorry..small change in Subject of Question---same value can NOT be selected in other dropdown list as i have already selected in prev dropdown list using Jquery

Comment: And that can be because you are only comparing A with others what if user first select dropdown B and then dropdown C

Comment: On page load only LocationA is enabled  other ddllist is disabled.. when i select LocationA then LocationB will be enabled and when i select LocationB then LocationC will be enabled and so on. And i have pasted code for only LocationA   and i have simillar code inside of chnage event of LocationB also.

Comment: Then you could delete the previously selected input from the others. Instead of just pointing to the error avoid the user from selecting it

Comment: Then add more code so that we can figure out where exactly the problem lies

Comment: No. my requirement is like: in LocationA if i have selected INDIA and in LocationB i have selected USA. and further if i am going to change LocationA value from INDIA to USA it should give me that alert("You have already selected same value in other Location field. Please select different value.!"); and value should still be INDIA in LocationA. but here it is giving me alert message but vaulue is being chnaged from INDIA to USA in LocationA. in this case chnage event should not work if values are same. tell me how to stop index being chnaged

Comment: You have to put more code, because the code you are showing us, does not do what you are describing, something is being triggered.

Comment: i am not able to post full code it is giving error here. any other way to post my complete code?

Comment: My simple question is if ddl1 and ddl2 i have two dropdown. inside .change event of dll2 i am checking that if the index value which i am selecting in dll2 it is already selecetd in dll1 then in that case index of dll2 should not be changes it should have prev value.

Comment: Hi Usman please see code in codepen: https://codepen.io/aditya2788/pen/ZazbQL

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').on('change', function(event ) {
var prevValue = $(this).data('previous');
$('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+prevValue+'"]').show();    
  var value = $(this).val();
 $(this).data('previous',value); 
  $('select').not(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();
 });
});
```

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/dollarsview/pen/dZboRz)

ps. Instead of removing options, you can hide/show them based on the value in other dropdows. Hope this helps :)

Comment: let me know if there is anything else in it

Comment: $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationA").change(function () {

        if ($("#ddlTitanVlanLocationA").val() == "") {

            $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationB").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
            $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationB").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationC").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
            $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationC").attr('disabled', true);
            $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationD").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
            $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationD").attr('disabled', true);

        }

Comment: else {
            $("#ddlTitanVlanLocationB").removeAttr('disabled');
        }

Comment: what's this ? >